# Facebook messenger

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I sent him a friend request and then sent him a message. Appears message went to others folder. He then accepted my friend request but message is still in others. If I sent him another message will it go to his inbox? Please help this is my only form of contact.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Once someone accepted the friend request, all your messages will go to inbox.